# I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, can anyone find what I'm doing wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the directions I was given:

Write a select statement that returns four columns based on the InvoiceTotal column of the MyInvoices table.

1. In the first column, use the CAST function to return InvoiceTotal as data type decimal with 2 digits to the right of the decimal point.
   i.  HINT: You can cast with Length and Decimal count using something like ‘as decimal(20, 2)’
2. The second columns should use CAST to return InvoiceTotal as a VarChar
3. The third column will use the CONVERT function to return the InvoiceTotal column as the same data type as the first column.
   i.  HINT: Use decimal conversion syntax similar to question 1.a.
4. The fourth column will use CONVERT to return the InvoiceTotal column as a varchar, using style 1.

This is the code I have:

```
SELECT InvoiceTotal
    CAST(InvoiceTotal AS decimal(20,2)) AS column1
    CAST(InvoiceTotal AS varchar) AS column2
    CONVERT(decimal, InvoiceTotal, 2) AS column3
    CONVERT(varchar, InvoiceTotal, 1) AS column4
FROM MyInvoices;
```

Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some commas, and a size for `varchar()`, and your converts have a style parameter, but I am not sure if that is intentional.

```
select 
    InvoiceTotal
  , CAST(InvoiceTotal as decimal(20, 2)) as column1 
  , CAST(InvoiceTotal as varchar(32)) as column2 /* set a size for varchar() */
  , CONVERT(decimal(20, 2), InvoiceTotal) as column3 /* specify size for decimal the same as in your cast */
  , CONVERT(varchar(32), InvoiceTotal) as column4 /* set a size for varchar() */
from MyInvoices;
```